# Retrieve average length of character of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a help to retrieve the value of a dictionary.
The dictionary:

```
{'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '111', 'y': '10'}
```

And the probabilities of the character:

```
[('m', 0.16666666666666666), ('a', 0.5), ('s', 0.16666666666666666), ('y', 0.16666666666666666)]
```

The problem is how to retrieve the length of each character and multiply it with the probabilities of each character to get the average length of character. For example:

```
a=1*0.5
y=2*0.16666666666666666
m=3*0.16666666666666666
s=3*0.16666666666666666
```

The final answer should be:

```
average length of character: 1.83
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum1=0
for prob in probs:
    sum1+=len(d[prob[0]])*prob[1]
print("average length of character:",sum1)
```

#### Output

> average length of character: 1.8333333333333333

Answer (score 1):

Using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with an appropriate [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) producing the probability weighted lengths:

```
chars = {'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '111', 'y': '10'}
probs = [('m', 0.16666666666666666), ('a', 0.5), ('s', 0.16666666666666666), ('y', 0.16666666666666666)]


avg_len = sum(p * len(chars[c]) for c, p in probs)
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --- prob-weighted length of char c
# 1.8333333333333333

print('average length of character: {:.2f}'.format(avg_len))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
d = {'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '111', 'y': '10'}
p = [('m', 0.16666666666666666), ('a', 0.5), ('s', 0.16666666666666666), ('y', 0.16666666666666666)]
print('average length of character: %.2f' % sum(len(d[k]) * v for k, v in p))
```

This outputs:

```
average length of character: 1.83
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3, that would be:

```
strings = {'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '111', 'y': '10'}
probabilities = dict ([('m', 0.16666666666666666), ('a', 0.5), ('s', 0.16666666666666666), ('y', 0.16666666666666666)])

averageLength = 0
for key in strings:
    averageLength += len (strings [key]) * probabilities [key]

print (averageLength)
```

Note: This program uses a simple loop, which I think is easy to comprehend if you're new to Python. Other answers use a thing called a list comprehension. Once you understand what these do, they are to be preferred in many cases, although a bit harder to debug since you can't single-step through them.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '111', 'y': '10'}
>>> a = dict([('m', 0.16666666666666666), ('a', 0.5), ('s', 0.16666666666666666), ('y', 0.16666666666666666)])
>>> sum([len(d[key])*a[key] for key in d.keys()])
1.8333333333333333
```

This simple approach might help you getting your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lambda` and the built-in `sum` function:

```
d = {'m': '110', 'a': '0', 's': '111', 'y': '10'}
prob = [('m', 0.16666666666666666), ('a', 0.5), ('s', 0.16666666666666666), ('y', 0.16666666666666666)]

avg = sum(map(lambda p : (len(d[p[0]])*p[1]), prob))
```

[This](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/lambda-map-and-filter-in-python-4935f248593) is a very nice guide about how to use lambda in Python